# unity VR- how to stop player move after it reaches the last waypoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, waypoint

While Unity was developing VR content,
I want to create a script that stops at the last Waypoint while moving to the Waypoint route,
But I have very rudimentary skills in C# Coding, (I tried my best, but I failed) so I would like to ask you for help...

This is the script that goes back to the first Waypoint,
Could you help me Please??
I'd really appreciate your help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{

    //이동방식 열거형 변수 선언
    public enum MoveType
    {
        WAY_POINT,
        LOOK_AT,
        DAYDREAM

    }

    //이동방식
    public MoveType moveType = MoveType.WAY_POINT;
    //이동속도
    public float speed = 1.0f;
    //회전속도
    public float damping = 3.0f;
    public int zero = 0;

    //모든 웨이포인트를 저장할 배열
    public Transform[] points;

    //트랜스톰 컴포넌트를 저장할 변수
    private Transform tr;
    //다음에 이동해야할 위치 인덱스 변수
    private int nextIdx = 1;

    void Start()
    {

        //트랜스폼 컴포넌트 추출후 변수 저장
        tr = GetComponent<Transform>();

        //포인트 게임오브젝트를 검색해 변수에 저장
        GameObject WayPointGroup = GameObject.Find("WayPointGroup");

        if(WayPointGroup != null)
        {

            //웨이포인트 하위에 모든 게임 오브젝트 Transfotm 컴포넌트 추출
            points = WayPointGroup.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        }
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        switch (moveType)
        {
            case MoveType.WAY_POINT:
                MoveWayPoint();
                break;

            case MoveType.LOOK_AT:
                break;

            case MoveType.DAYDREAM:
                break;

        }
        
    }

    //웨이포인트 경로로 이동하는 로직

    void MoveWayPoint()
    {
        //현재 위치에서 다음 웨이포인트로 향하는 벡터를 계산
        Vector3 direction = points[nextIdx].position - tr.position;
        //산출된 벡터의 회전 각도를 쿼터니언 타입으로 산출
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        //현재 각도에서 회전해야 할 각도까지 부드럽게 회전처리
        tr.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(tr.rotation, rot, Time.deltaTime * damping);

        //전진 방향으로 이동처리
        tr.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        //웨이포인트 - 포인트 게임 오브텍트 충돌여부 판단
        if (coll.CompareTag("WAY_POINT"))
        {
            //맨 마지막 웨이포인트에 도달했을 때 처음 인덱스로 변경
            nextIdx = (++nextIdx >= points.Length) ? 1 : nextIdx;
           
        }

        
      

    }

 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i am not sure if this script is a predefined one.

But the strategy behind your problem is quite simple.

- Create a variable containing always the last waypoint
- Write logic to overwrite this when reaching the next waypoints
- also set it to null after reaching the last waypoint.
- And while a waypoint is set (waypoint != null) then move towards the
  waypoint.

I described it like so because there are plenty ways to accomplish this waypoint system - be creative.

Also..

To Simplify your code i would use Vector3.moveTowards() and transform.lookAt() methods. With those you can easily reach your goal.

Vector3.MoveTowards() moves a object from one point to another point by given time*speed

transform.LookAt(DestTransform) makes this current Transforms positive z axis look at the direction of the transfrom. If this does not fit your needs try to modify the transform afterwards instead of complex rotation actions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. As you told me, I'll create script and try it today!